# zabbix user sudo issue in mdraid monitoring

Tags: sudo, zabbix

I am trying to use this script to monitor software raids:
https://github.com/linuxsquad/zabbix_mdraid

When I have the following setting (with SUDO) in zabbix_agentd.conf:

```
UserParameter=mdraid[*], sudo /usr/local/bin/zabbix_mdraid.sh -m'$1' -$2'$3'
UserParameter=mdraid.discovery, sudo /usr/local/bin/zabbix_mdraid.sh -D
```

And execute the following from Zabbix proxy:

```
zabbix_get -s HOSTNAME -k mdraid[/dev/md0,d,1]
```

I am getting the following error ("sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo") in zabbix_agentd.log:

```
25547:20141229:090259.961 Requested [mdraid[/dev/md0,d,1]]
25547:20141229:090259.961 In zbx_popen() command:' sudo /usr/local/bin/zabbix_mdraid.sh -m'/dev/md0' -d'1''
25547:20141229:090259.962 End of zbx_popen():7
25552:20141229:090259.962 zbx_popen(): executing script
sudo 25546:20141229:090259.970 listener #1 [processing request]
25546:20141229:090259.970 Requested [system.cpu.util[,steal]]
25546:20141229:090259.970 Sending back [0.000000]
25546:20141229:090259.970 listener #1 [waiting for connection]
: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Yes, I have already tweaked /etc/sudoers file:

```
/etc/sudoers:
zabbix ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Defaults:zabbix !requiretty
```

Also tried commenting out all lines that contain requiretty in /etc/sudoers

when I switch to zabbix user and run the script manually:

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo /usr/local/bin/zabbix_mdraid.sh -m'/dev/md0' -eState
clean,degraded-bash-4.1$
```

It works just fine. So the script is good and /etc/sudoers does not require tty for zabbix user. What else can be wrong? Any ideas how to make this work?

This is RHEL 6.5 by the way (agent, proxy and server)

Comment: For me works just adding: `zabbix ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. OS: **Debian**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when monitoring MegaRAID hardware on a XenServer host (CentOS based).
In the end I just needed to comment out this line:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

from `/etc/sudoers` and it worked. From what I've read it can be safely removed, and will be removed by RedHat in the future. I didn't need to add anything to the `Defaults` line (like you did for `zabbix`).

Of course the last test works for you because when you manually run the command you do are in a tty ;)

Comment: Thank you but as I have already mentioned, I have tried this too.

Comment: Did you completely comment the Defaults line?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable SELinux:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

In RHEL and Centos it is enabled by default